# MySQL and Workbench on MacBook Catalina - No connection established 3306 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, macos, localhost, port, mysql-workbench

I cannot connect to database on localhost created in Work bench - I have tried changing pid to 16000 and to 3307 and other suggestions on Stack Overflow to no avail. In Workbench I was able to create a table  and a schema showing the table, but I can not add data to it. Problem seems to be "No connection established". SQL Preferences shows SQL is running. SQL is 8.0.21, MacOS 10.15 X86_64

Comment: what happened between being able to create a table and the "No connection established" message? If you run the command `sudo lsof -i -n -P` from the console do you see port 3306 listed?

Comment: I do not know if the "No connection established" was there before i created the table.

Comment: Sorry to be slow replying, internet connection problems.

Comment: no worries... did you have a chance to run the command mentioned above? Regarding the message, it shouldn't have been there when you created the table or the creation of the table would itself have failed.

Comment: I could not use the "sudo .." command from the console - it demanded a password and then refused to let me enter the password. There was a character representing a white key in a blue background. I cannot get rid of. Incidentely I assume by console you meant terminal - if not I can not find a console at all.

Comment: yes, indeed, I meant terminal. I don't think it was refusing to enter the password, it probably is just that it doesn't show what you are typing to hide the password from potential passersby. The "sudo" bit is to enable root authentication, that way guaranteeing that we'll see all processes listed, but if you don't manage to get through the password prompt try just `lsof -i -n -P`. It should list the ports being used, and if we see there that port 3306 is listed and associated to MySQL we validate that you're trying to connect to a running service.

Comment: I also find that though there is a worbench "dbM....C.wdb" created by workbench I can not access a database from MySQL - password again I'm not sure but doesw not MySQL Workbench hold it's data in a "model" database and then export the database so defined to a database in MySQL to which it is linked ?

Comment: I tried double clicking in Macintosh HD/usr/local/mysql/bin/ on mysql and also on Macintosh HD/usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/bin/ which kicked of a terminal session with the following result

Comment: Last login: Fri Oct 16 22:19:36 on ttys000

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Nigels-MacBook-Pro:~ nigelheath$ /usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/bin/mysql ; exit;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'nigelheath'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: OK I tried the Sudo command again and this time to my surprise it worked the result was as follow

Comment: nigelheath$ sudo lsof -i -n -P
Password:
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
launchd      1            root   30u  IPv4 0x4370c7b12168c895      0t0    UDP *:137
launchd      1            root   31u  IPv4 0x4370c7b12168cb7d      0t0    UDP *:138
syslogd     92            root   12u  IPv4 0x4370c7b12bb972c5      0t0    UDP *:63249
UserEvent   93            root  175u  IPv6 0x4370c7b12532ae0d      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49152->[fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe33:4455]:59602 (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: UserEvent   93            root  176u  IPv6 0x4370c7b12532b42d      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49153 (LISTEN)
UserEvent   93            root  177u  IPv6 0x4370c7b125329bad      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49154 (LISTEN)
UserEvent   93            root  178u  IPv6 0x4370c7b12532ba4d      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49155 (LISTEN)
UserEvent   93            root  179u  IPv6 0x4370c7b12532c06d      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49156 (LISTEN)

Comment: UserEvent   93            root  180u  IPv6 0x4370c7b12532958d      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49157 (LISTEN)
systemsta  102            root   17u  IPv4 0x4370c7b124bb1a0d      0t0    UDP *:*
configd    103            root   14u  IPv4 0x4370c7b124a84895      0t0    UDP *:*
configd    103            root   17u  IPv4 0x4370c7b124a8514d      0t0    UDP *:*
configd    103            root   18u  IPv4 0x4370c7b124b7c2c5      0t0    UDP *:*
configd    103            root   20u  IPv4 0x4370c7b124a8aa0d      0t0    UDP *:*

Comment: configd    103            root   21u  IPv4 0x4370c7b12449ecf5      0t0    UDP *:*
configd    103            root   24u  IPv6 0x4370c7b136b50b7d      0t0 ICMPV6 *:*
logd       109            root   12u  IPv6 0x4370c7b125328f6d      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49158->[fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe33:4455]:49651 (ESTABLISHED)
apsd       126            root   10u  IPv4 0x4370c7b138bfe49d      0t0    TCP 192.168.3.12:54971->17.57.146.149:5223 (ESTABLISHED)
locationd  133      _locationd    8u  IPv4 0x4370c7b12bb97895      0t0    UDP *:*

Comment: That covers a selection of the list that came back. I tried searching with cmd + F for 3306 and for 127.0.0. neither of which were found - to make sense of the list it mak be necessary to copy and reformat in a tetx file.

Comment: to locasreta - many thanks for your help - I think that MySQL Workbench stores the table definitions etc in a file of its own not in the MySQL database -  I am root user so in my comment yesterday I don't understand why I was denied access - I have just brought an Oracle Press book on MySQL Workbench, which suggests to me that although I have installed MySQL there may be some further steps needed to complete installation

Comment: OK I tried reinstalling, carefully screenshotting each step and stopping and starting MySQL but I still get Local instance 3306 Not Connected and Server Status - Stopped

Comment: ran Sudo which resulted in two lines as follows

Comment: mysqld    9999          _mysql   29u  IPv6 0x4370c7b13aff794d      0t0    TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
mysqld    9999          _mysql   31u  IPv6 0x4370c7b13aff91cd      0t0    TCP *:16000 (LISTEN)

Comment: which shows the system TCP *.33060 and TCP *.16000 but not 3306

Comment: Also my reinstall seemed to show that I have not missed out any necessary steps. So despite all these efforts I do not seem to be any further forward.

Comment: try changing the connection port in Workbench to 33060 instead of 3306, with user root and empty password, or user root and password "root"... seems like connection could be failing because you were trying to connect to a different port

Comment: Thank you lucasreta I tried this in Modify Server Connections with the results as follows - Line 1 - The specified item could not be found in the keychain. (-25300)
Line 2 - 
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:33060 with user root
Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10
Part of my problem is that after years as a database developer I have always had a technical support department to handle problems like this, I was trained for Cobol programing and system design, and Codasyl and used Pick Databases (both very old) extensively and then used MS Access and SQL Server.

Comment: Final Comment - After trying everything - I uninstalled MySQL, MySQL Workbench and MySQL Shell 8.0.21 and reinstalled 8.0.22 and also included <string>--port=16000</string> in .plist and the server connection and finally it worked.